# Regex remove a special and duplicated character from the string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem to write a regex to remove a special and duplicated character from a string in javascript. Because I need to compare the date like type of this

```
2015-11-05-14:30
```

so I'm going to transform the date string into integer number

```
201511051430
```

and make it comparable. And so, I need to remove the character "**-**" & "**:**" !

Comment: `str.replace(/[-:]/g,'');` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsisodia91/xv6ewquL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the following regex

```
/[-:]/g
```

OR you can simply use

```
/\D/g
```

- `\D` will match any character i.e. not a digit
- `g` for global modifier

**Javascript :**

```
str.replace(/[-:]/g,'');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsisodia91/xv6ewquL/)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be converting this into a timestamp instead of a custom "date-ish" number:

```
> +new Date('2015/11/05 14:30')
1446708600000
```

You can not only compare this, but your comparisons can be meaningful (e.g. you can figure out how many days apart 2 dates are).

Based on your original format:

```
var timestamp = +new Date(dateStr.replace(/-(?=\d+:)/, ' ').replace(/-/g, '/'));
```

Comment: this format is neither working in safari or in firefox

Comment: @Sean -- My bad.  Forgot that they don't like dashes.  Fixed.